# INotifyPropertyChanged and animation of changing data

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, binding, inotifypropertychanged

In my application I have the scenario where I have a rectangle indicating information based on its width which is just a custom progress bar. I don't have its width bound to a ViewModels property since the changes aren't smooth and the bar would look choppy yet I wanted to have smooth animations when the data changes.

Therefore my event handler that is reacting to the `PropertyChanged` event of its underlying dependency is notifying the respective properties that should be reflected in the UI but the rectangle is handled differently. Basically it runs

```
Rectangle.BeginAnimation(FrameworkElement.WidthProperty,
    new DoubleAnimation(width, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(200)));
```

I was curious whether it is reasonable to introduce a property for the width that raises the `PropertyChanged` event when it changes and then to animate this property so that the rectangle gets animated by animating the width property in my ViewModel. Is it even possible to animate custom properties in that scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may create an attached property `TargetWidth` that animates the `Width` property of a FrameworkElement when set.

```
public static class FrameworkElementExtension
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TargetWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "TargetWidth",
            typeof(double),
            typeof(FrameworkElementExtension),
            new PropertyMetadata(TargetWidthPropertyChanged));

    public static double GetTargetWidth(this FrameworkElement obj)
    {
        return (double)obj.GetValue(TargetWidthProperty);
    }

    public static void SetTargetWidth(this FrameworkElement obj, double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(TargetWidthProperty, value);
    }

    private static void TargetWidthPropertyChanged(
        DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var element = obj as FrameworkElement;
        if (element != null)
        {
            if (double.IsNaN(element.Width))
            {
                element.Width = 0;
            }

            element.BeginAnimation(
                FrameworkElement.WidthProperty,
                new DoubleAnimation((double)e.NewValue, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.2)));
        }
    }
}
```

You may now either directly set the `TargetWidth` like

```
Rectangle.SetTargetWidth(width);
```

or bind it to a view model property:

```
<Rectangle ... local:FrameworkElementExtension.TargetWidth="{Binding RectangleWidth}" />
```

Comment: Even though I have added a default value for the `Width` on the `Rectangle` somewhere NaN appeared. Thus I had to add the `fromValue` to the `DoubleAnimation` by referencing it using `element.ActualWidth` then your solution worked. Just a quick question about animations: assume I get an update of the value while the last animation hasn't finished yet, will the second invoked animation be executed after the first or starting for the very moment such that no lag it noticed?

Comment: It will start immediately from the current value. Therefore I wouldn't recommend to set the animation's From value. Better make sure that Width isn't initially NaN.

Comment: Nevermind, something strange was happening - manually setting the default `Width` in the XAML for the `Rectangle` did not help earlier, but it does now to prevent NaN. It works now as expected.